# MakeJavaObject on list of inhomogeneous objects belonging to the same base class

Tags: java

When using J/Link, how can we create an array out of objects belonging to different classes but having the same base class?

Here's an example:

```
partSource = 
  JLink`JavaNew[
   "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.ByteArrayPartSource", "mmagraphics.png", 
   JLink`MakeJavaObject["abcdefg"]@toCharArray[]];
part1 = JLink`JavaNew[
   "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart", 
   "filename", partSource];
part2 = JLink`JavaNew[
   "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.StringPart", 
   "someting", "1234"];

MakeJavaObject[{part1, part2}]
```

> Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method).

I need to create a [`Part []`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/Part.html) out of `{part1, part2}` so that I can pass it to the constructor of `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity`

Comment: This is for fixing the uploader palette which was broken by API changes today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can start by creating the parts using the same code as the question:

```
partSource = 
  JavaNew[
    "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.ByteArrayPartSource",
    "mmagraphics.png", 
    MakeJavaObject["abcdefg"]@toCharArray[]];

part1 =
  JavaNew[
    "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart", 
    "filename", partSource];

part2 =
  JavaNew[
    "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.StringPart", 
    "someting", "1234"];
```

We want to create an array whose components are of the type `Part`.  We will need a reference to that class.  A normal JLink reference is not good enough -- we need the Java object that represents the class.  We use the JLink class loader to get this reference:

```
LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"];

partClass =
  JLinkClassLoader`classFromName[
    "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part"];
```

We can then use the [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class to create an array of the correct type and fill in its elements:

```
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.reflect.Array"];

parts =
  ReturnAsJavaObject @ Array`newInstance[partClass, 2];
Array`set[parts, 0, part1]
Array`set[parts, 1, part2]
```

Note carefully the use of `ReturnAsJavaObject`.  Without it, the carefully constructed array would be immediately converted back to a Mathematica list.

We now have everything we need to construct the required `MultipartRequestEntity`:

```
post =
  JavaNew[
    "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod",
    "http://somewhere/over/the/rainbow"];

multipart = JavaNew[
  "org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity",
  parts,  
  post@getParams[]]

(* JavaObject[org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity] *)
```

Comment: +1 for the JLinkClassLoader`classFromName[] tip.